# Where to store static files in the cloud used by the application?

Tags: c#, deployment, cloud, storage

My application refers to a bunch of xsd files which are used for xml validation. Currently, they are stored in my local directory and I refer it by giving a path to the primary xsd like "C:\TestFolder\TestFile.xsd". This path is stored in the mongo database. I am not sure where do I store the files once I host this application on the Cloud(Azure). And how do I refer that path in mongo? Since there would be many instances of this application running on the cloud, I am not sure what is the best way to solve this problem.

One way could be to store the files in the project and refer them but I don't think that is the best way.

Can someone point me in the right direction?
The xsd files are not changed by the application, they are just used for validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1 (Simple). Make sure you are using the Relative Path and not the Absolute Path when dealing with the files. Also, make sure to import the files into the project and set the “Copy to Output Directory” property to “Copy Always” so that it can be accessed at run time.

Solution 2. You could store your static files as Blob files on Azure and then reference them (there are many tutorials available out there on how to do it). This way, should you accidentally delete your application, those files will not be lost.

Comment: I used Solution 2. I stored the XSD files in Azure Blob Storage and made the container public and accessed it via the public url which is stored in the mongo database. I was already using Blob Storage for some other purpose in the application. Adding this was not that difficult. As you said, there are many tutorials out there.